# Average volume in Google sheet

Tags: volume, trading, weighted-average

Hi can somebody sent a formula of :
1.comparision of average trading volume of last 5days &20 days earlier to it.
2. Comparison of average trading volume of last 20days & 80 days earlier to it.
Remember 5 days not count in 20 days .
20days not count in 80 days .

Hi can somebody sent a formula of :

1.comparision of average trading volume of last 5days &20 days earlier to it.

2. Comparison of average trading volume of last 20days & 80 days earlier to it.

Remember 5 days not count in 20 days .

20days not count in 80 days .